# Form for additional attributes of join model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

A User has many Skills through UserSkills.
A Skill has many Users through UserSkills.

In my new user form, I'm able to add checkboxes for skills but if I add a Proficiency (string) attribtue to the UserSkills model, how can I include this?

My current code:

```
<%= f.label :skills %>
<%= hidden_field_tag "user[skill_ids][]", nil %>
<% Skill.all.each do |skill| %>
<%= check_box_tag "user[skill_ids][]", skill.id, @user.skill_ids.include?(skill.id), id: dom_id(skill) %>
<%= link_to skill.skilltitle, skill_path(skill.id) %>
```

Comment: As litle help, you can use formtastic, is very helpful for this type of multi-model forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_skills
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_skills
end

class UserSkill < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :skill

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :skill
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

... meanwhile.. in your form

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :user_skills do |f2| %>
    <%# add your user_skill attributes here %>
    <%= f2.check_box :proficiency %>
    <%= f2.fields_for :user do |f3| %>
      <%#  user attributes to go here %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```